# Question about convergence of moments $\Rightarrow$ convergence of distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, weak-convergence

Let $\{X_n:n\geq1\}$ be random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(0\leq X_n \leq 1)=1$ for all $n\geq 1$. Suppose that $\mathbb{E}(X_n^k)\rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X^k)$ for all $k\geq 1$ where $X$ is a r.v. We have to show that $$X_n \xrightarrow{dist.}X$$

**My approach:**

I use characteristic function to conclude that. That is

$$\big|\varphi_n(t)-\varphi(t)\big| \\
= \bigg|\varphi_n(t)-\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(it)^j}{j!}\mathbb{E}(X_n^j)-\varphi(t)+\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(it)^j}{j!}\mathbb{E}(X^j)+\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(it)^j}{j!}\mathbb{E}(X_n^j)-\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(it)^j}{j!}\mathbb{E}(X^j)\bigg|$$
now by triangle inequality
$$\big|\varphi_n(t)-\varphi(t)\big|\leq \\ \bigg|\varphi_n(t)-\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(it)^j}{j!}\mathbb{E}(X_n^j)\bigg|+\bigg|\varphi(t)-\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(it)^j}{j!}\mathbb{E}(X^j)\bigg|+\bigg|\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(it)^j}{j!}\mathbb{E}(X_n^j)-\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(it)^j}{j!}\mathbb{E}(X^j)\bigg|\\
\leq \mathbb{E}\bigg(\min\bigg[\frac{|tX_n|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}, \frac{2|tX_n|^k}{k!}\bigg]\bigg) + \mathbb{E}\bigg(\min\bigg[\frac{|tX|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}, \frac{2|tX|^k}{k!}\bigg]\bigg) + \bigg|\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(it)^j}{j!}\mathbb{E}(X_n^j)-\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(it)^j}{j!}\mathbb{E}(X^j)\bigg|$$

Then for a fix $\epsilon > 0 \exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\big|\varphi_n(t)-\varphi(t)\big|<\epsilon$ from that we conclude that $X_n \xrightarrow{dist.}X$

If anyone proof using different method that can be appreciable.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2):

There is  a short proof if you are willing to use some well known theorems. The fact that $X_n$'s are supported by a compact set implies that every subsequence of $(X_n)$ has  further subsequence which converges in distribution. (In other words the distributions form a relatively compact set). So it is enough to show that there is at most one limit point. But this is true since moments determine  the distribution uniquely when the supports lie in a  compact set.  [Recall that convergence in distribution implies convergence of all moments for uniformly bounded random variables].